# How to retrieve variable from a method

Tags: java

I made a text adventure that turns into a card game based on an anime I enjoy, essentially I moved all my long winded text into private static voids in order to 'clean up' the main method. Firstly is this the best way to go about it? Second, and it is my main question, in public static String jojiFunai I ask user for his name. However I want to use this variable throughout the rest of the code, how can I go about this? Sorry this is a mouthful, I just don't know where to go.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Ecard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner intKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean emperor = false;
        boolean slave = false;

        // Player 1 Deck
        int emperorPlayer1 = 1;
        final int citizenPlayer1 = 4;
        // Player 2 Deck

        // opening options

        // activates which deck player chooses
        // boolean emperor= false, slave= false;

        int deckChoice;

        wakeUp();
        jojiFunai();

        System.out.println(name);
        gameRules();
        deckChoice();
//This portion will be turned into a class Deck
//      Random computer = new Random();
//
//      while (emperor = true && emperorPlayer1 != 0) {
//          System.out.println("What card will you put down ?");
//          System.out.println("Options: \n 1. emperor card(" + emperorPlayer1
//                  + ")");
//          System.out.println("2. citizen card(" + citizenPlayer1 + ")");
//          int computerChoice = computer.nextInt(2) + 1;
//          deckChoice = intKeyboard.nextInt();
//          if (deckChoice == 1) {
//              emperorPlayer1--;
//              System.out.println("You have placed a emperor card down.");
//              if (deckChoice == computerChoice) {
//                  System.out.println("It looks like you just lost,HAHAHA");
                }
            }
        }

        // This will talk about the rules of each deck and what deck has
        // what
        // final int emperorPlayer1 = 1;
        // final int citizenPlayer1 = 4;
        // Player 2 Deck
        // final int slavePlayer2 = 1;
        // final int citizenPlayer2 = 4;
        //

    }

    private static void wakeUp() {
        System.out.println("You awaken at the sound of your alarm clock,"
                + " do you go turn off the alarm? Y/N");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String alarm = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (alarm.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("As you hit the awake button you hear the"
                    + " sound of knocking at your front door.");
        } else if (alarm.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("You hit the snooze button"
                    + " and fall back into a deep sleep,"
                    + " avoiding what would have happened next. END");
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

    public static String jojiFunai() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner intKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out`enter code here`
                .println("As you reach for the door, you are suddenly hit from behind......");
        System.out
                .println("You hear the faint words coming from the figure 'We have him, we are talking him to the boat', darkness however surrounds you. ");
        System.out
                .println("................................................................");
        System.out
                .println("................................................................");
        System.out
                .println("................................................................");
        System.out
                .println("................................................................");
        System.out.println("'Hey buddy, wake up!!!!'");
        System.out.println("'Hey im talking to you! What is your name?'");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out
                .println("'Nice to meet you "
                        + name
                        + ". My name is Joji Funai and from what those people told me,"
                        + " looks like your my opponent for the card game we will be playing.'");
        System.out.println("OPTIONS:");
        System.out.println("1. Where am I?");
        System.out.println("2. Refuse.");
        System.out.println("3. Accept.");
        int funaiQuestion = intKeyboard.nextInt();
        switch (funaiQuestion) {
        case 1:
            System.out
                    .println("Your in a ship, seems that you signed a contract in which you failed to uphold, the only way you can pay up is through gambling.. so lets get started.");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out
                    .println("I wish you didnt say that' Joji instantly pulls out a pistol ending your life before you knew what happened");
            System.exit(0);
        case 3:
            System.out
                    .println("Without asking any questions? Someone has some confidence, I like that! now let me explain the rules....");
            break;

        }
        return name;

    }

    private static void gameRules() {
        System.out.println("///////////////////////////////GAME"
                + " RULES//////////////////////////////////////////////////");

        System.out.println("'This game is called E-Card, each player"
                + " takes turns playing three rounds"
                + " on the 'emperor' side and the 'slave' side.'");
        System.out.println("The game is starts with each player holding"
                + " five cards, four of which are Citizens"
                + " and the last being either a Slave or an Emperor."
                + " Who holds which card is decided beforehand,"
                + " and is played like that for three turns before switching.");
        System.out.println("The game lasts for a total of twelve turns,"
                + " meaning each side gets to play Emperor twice. ");
        System.out.println("The players choose one card from their hand"
                + " and place them face-down on the table."
                + " They are then flipped over to reveal the winner "
                + "of the match.The three card types are Citizen,"
                + " Emperor and Slave.");
        System.out.println("The Citizen card represents the common man,"
                + " and cannot defeat the Emperor who sits at"
                + " the top. It can, however, defeat the Slave,"
                + " who resides at the very bottom of the system."
                + " Two citizen against each other results in a tie.");
        System.out.println("The Emperor represents the one at the top of"
                + " society. This card can defeat the citizen,"
                + " but will lose to the Slave.");
        System.out.println("The Slave is presented as the one at the very"
                + " bottom of society. Seeing as how it has nothing"
                + " to lose, it can overthrow the Emperor in one last"
                + " attempt at revenge. This card will lose to a Citizen,"
                + " but will win against the Emperor card.");
        System.out.println("//////////////////////////////////////////////"
                + "GAME RULES///////////////////////////////////");

        System.out.println("Sorry for being so long winded, anyways, ill let"
                + " you choose first, would you like the \n 1.emperor"
                + " deck or the \n 2.slave deck?");

    }

    private static void deckChoice() {
        Scanner intKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int deckChoice = intKeyboard.nextInt();

        if (deckChoice == 1) {
            System.out.println("It looks like you chose the risky deck "
                    + " I like that!");
            boolean emperor = true;
        } else if (deckChoice == 2) {
            System.out.println("I can tell your frightened"
                    + ". Well i dont blame ya, HAHA");
            boolean slave = true;
        }
        System.out.println("Funai slams the deck on the table.");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You method is already returning the value, but you just need to capture it

```
    name = jojiFunai();
    System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: It seems like it now loops jojiFunai again but it does print the name off the second time it looped

Comment: There are no loops in your code, and jojiFunal method is only called once.  One major things I would do is not create multiple Scanner Objects, just do it once and re-use the variable in your method, either by having the Scanner object as a field or by passing the Scanner Object as a parameter to the methods.

Comment: I believe when I assigned String name to jojiFunai(); it made it loop once more, I wonder why it does that.